# MemoryLoadError while Iterating with Openpyxl

Tags: python, error-handling, out-of-memory, openpyxl

As I am iterating through a series of `.xlsm` and `.xlsx` files, I am trying to copy the first sheet into a storage workbook. However, after about 30-40 files, I start to exclusively get a `MemoryError` from even some very small `.xlsx` files. I feel as though it shouldn't be too taxing to individually open excel files.

I believe I'm saving and closing the necessary files. But clearly I'm overloading the memory somewhere. Any ideas?

```
import logging
import os
import openpyxl as xl

from copy import copy
from zipfile import BadZipFile

# Create and configure logger
LOG_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename="errors.log",
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    format = LOG_FORMAT,
                    filemode ='w')
logger = logging.getLogger()


def copy_paste_sheets(sheet_giv, sheet_rec, filename_giv='', filename_rec='', start_row=1, start_col=1, end_row=None, end_col=None, offset_row=0, offset_col=0):

    if end_row == None:
        end_row = sheet_giv.max_row
    if end_col == None:
        end_col = sheet_giv.max_column


    print(f"Copying and Pasting {filename_giv} {sheet_giv} to {filename_rec}{sheet_rec}...")
    for i in range(start_row, end_row + 1):
        for j in range(start_col, end_col + 1):

            giv_cell = sheet_giv.cell(row=i, column=j)            
            rec_cell = sheet_rec.cell(row=i+offset_row, column=j+offset_col, value=giv_cell.value)

            if giv_cell.has_style:
                rec_cell.font = copy(giv_cell.font)
                rec_cell.border = copy(giv_cell.border)
                rec_cell.fill = copy(giv_cell.fill)
                rec_cell.number_format = copy(giv_cell.number_format)
                rec_cell.protection = copy(giv_cell.protection)
                rec_cell.alignment = copy(giv_cell.alignment)


def main():
    directory = r'C:\path'

rec_wb = xl.Workbook()

    for n, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)):
        if filename.endswith(".xlsx") or filename.endswith(".xlsm"):
            try:
                giv_wb = xl.load_workbook(filename=os.path.join(directory, filename))
                giv_ws = giv_wb.worksheets[0]

                rec_ws = rec_wb.create_sheet(str(n), -1)
                title_cell = rec_ws.cell(row=1, column=1)
                title_cell.value = filename
                copy_paste_sheets(giv_ws, rec_ws, filename_giv=filename, end_row=50, end_col=15, offset_row=1)


            except (BadZipFile, MemoryError) as e:
                if type(e) == MemoryError:
                    e = 'MemoryError'

                print(f'No: {n} - {filename} = {e}')
                logger.error(f'No: {n} - {filename} = {e}')
    
        giv_wb.close()

        elif not filename.endswith(".xlsx") or not filename.endswith(".xlsm"):
            logger.info(f'No: {n} - {filename} = Not xlsx or xlsm file')

        rec_wb.save("output.xlsx")
        rec_wb.close()
        rec_wb =  xl.load_workbook(filename="output.xlsx")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `giv_wb.close()` should probably be at the bottom of the `try` block, under `copy_paste_sheets`

Comment: Unfortunately that's how I initially set it up. It doesn't work I'm afraid. I moved it outside of the conditionals to make sure that it was getting closed every loop, but that still hasn't fixed it and I have no idea why.

Comment: I added gc.collect() to the end of the the loop, and that seemed to have mostly fixed it. But it's getting to the 80th file (n of 79) and it just seems to pause for a very long time until it crashes. Intially it was a XMLSyntax Error that was causing it. But when I added that Error to the exception it still just crashes.

Comment: If memory is an issue, use read-only mode though you'll need to adjust the code for dealing with styles. Also move the code for processing out of the try/except block.

Comment: Can you incorporate styles when in read-only mode? I'll try moving the processing out of the try/except block now.

Comment: For performance reasons, styles in read-only mode are a bit more "hands-on" but they're there. You just don't have the `has_style` shortcut.

Comment: By moving the copy function out of the try block, it did seem to perform better. Do you want to post a full response so I can mark it correct? It still crashes on particularly large files, but I'm guessing the read_only mode will correct this. I haven't found any examples the retain the equivalent style copying features.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by adding `gc.collect()` to the end of my loop

Comment: This shouldn't really be necessary.

Comment: It's also not working perfectly either. It gets further, but it still crashes with particularly large excel files.